# How do I get a complete list of the classes in MFC and ATL?

Tags: mfc, atl

I need for documentation purposes the list of all classes public available in MFC and in ATL. How can I build this list without copy and paste from all header files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx) is always a good place to start.

You can download [this handy chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws8s10w4.aspx), and even hang it on your wall. Multiple formats are available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=294EB161-6855-4ABD-99B4-325C66A78377&displaylang=en).

And for [ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1c35cc3.aspx). Classes *shared* between ATL and MFC are all listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzs00fs6.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).  You can point it to the headers in \Vc7\atlmfc\include and it will create HTML (and other formats) of the public members.